# How to change a css class on a div tag in jquery based on a certain condition

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="required">
<label for="personID">People</label>
<select name="personID" id="personID"  class="select">
<option value="" selected="selected" >No One Selected</option>
<option value="groupA" >Group A</option>
<option value="groupB" >Group B</option>
...
```

And I have this HTML:

```
<div class="visControl optional" style="display: none;">
<label for="refNum">Reference Number</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="refNum" id="refNum">
</div>
```

And I have the following SCRIPT:

```
<script>
  $('#personID').change(function() {
    if ($('#personID').val() == 'groupB') $('.visControl').show();
    else $('.visControl').hide();
  }); // end .change()
</script>
```

My script properly controls the visibility of the Reference Number block. But what I want it to also do is change the class attribute from "optional" to "required" to match the visibility.

In other words, when I *show* the Reference Number block I want the `div.optional` to become `div.required` and when I *hide* the Reference Number block I want the `div.required` to become `div.optional`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

Change:

```
if ($('#personID').val() == 'groupB') $('.visControl').show();
else $('.visControl').hide();
```

to:

```
if ($('#personID').val() == 'groupB') $('.visControl').show().toggleClass('required  optional');
else $('.visControl').hide().toggleClass('required  optional');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8GA5u/)**

Comment: That is not working for me. I no longer get the block to show or hide

Comment: I just added a fiddle to my answer. If you watch the DOM while changing the select, you'll see the class change.

Comment: Ok, thanks @j08691 -- I see that it should work so I need to play around with it in my script. I'll post back later once I get it figured out.

Comment: awesome @j8691 -- exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: actually @j8691 this is pretty close to what I need. After I tested it I recognized that the toggle keeps alternating the optional and required. What I actually need is `required` when .show() and `optional` when .hide() something like what [at]CamTullos has below but maybe on one line of code versus 2 lines of code

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('div.optional').addClass('required'); 
$('div.optional').removeClass('optional');
```

Comment: I think part of your answer @CamTullos and part of [at]j8691is what I need combined into 1. This is working but I am wondering if it cn be simplified or combined into 1 line of code `if ($('#personID').val() == 'groupB') { $('.visControl').show().addClass('required'); $('.visControl').show().removeClass('optional'); }
else { $('.visControl').hide().addClass('optional'); $('.visControl').hide().removeClass('required'); }`

Comment: Also, what id the div class already has optional or required. Does this keep adding more like classes or does is just add them once?